# ¿Puedo alojar todas las variables en un archivo independiente de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un proyectito, y quiero definir muchas variables. Pero me queda un codigo medio feo. Me gustaría alojarlas en otro js donde solo hayan variables y tenes mi js donde le doy la funcionalida a las mismas.

Ejemplo:

uno.js

```
var uno = 1;
var dos = 2;
```

dos.js

```
var suma = uno + dos;
```

Comment: Hola, por que no usas json?

Comment: si puedes ya paso la pregunta para que se explique mejor

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido, pero puedes hacerlo sin problema. Guarda las variables en otro archivo y solo asegúrate de incluirlo antes de los otros scripts que las van a usar. `<script src="uno.js"></script><script src="dos.js"></script>`